# How to run coverage report on a Postgres extension

Tags: postgresql, code-coverage

I found out that there is a possibility to run run tests with coverage reports in PostgreSQL and this is also available for PostgreSQL extensions (from PGXN).

I have found two repositories that include coverage reports:

- https://github.com/theory/sqitch (unfortunately this is perl)
- https://github.com/citusdata/cstore_fdw (this is in c, but I can't figure how to run coverage test out from this example)

How do I run coverage reports locally on an extension? I think this should be provided by the generic PGXN Makefile.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/jasonmp85/9963879) and [this](https://gist.github.com/petere/6023944).

Comment: As far as I understand it
`export enable_coverage=yes

make install

make installcheck`

should be called, however this doesn't generate the coverage report for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local coverage report may be achieved by:

1. Installing Postgres with --enable-coverage flag
2. Building the extension against the Postgres installation and it's pg_config
3. Adding and calling target from the extension's Makefile

> ```
> coverage: 
> lcov -d . -c -o lcov.info
> genhtml --show-details --legend --output-directory=coverage --title=PostgreSQL --num-spaces=4 --prefix=./src/ `find . -name lcov.info -print`
> ```

Credits go to Ronan Dunklau from pgxn-users mailing list.